# Archlinux does not boot from sda2

Tags: arch-linux, boot, grub

Due to the lack of space on the EFI partition in sda1 (128 MB), I was forced to configure an existing Archlinux system with EFI (/boot) on sda2. The reconfiguration process from USB (pacstrap, arch-chroot, grub setup) completes successfully (no errors), but upon reboot, the system cannot find the bootloader files.

Comment: please share partition layout and file systems, it should be known how many `EFI` partitions are there currently.

Comment: If the `efibootmgr -v` output indicates the boot variable is correctly constructed and points to the correct partition (use `lsblk -o +PARTUUID` and verify that the PARTUUID listed for `sda2` matches the one listed in the boot variable), then it's a UEFI firmware issue. But if `sda2` is located immediately after `sda1` on the disk, then you could boot from some live Linux media that includes `gparted`, and then **delete `sda2` and extend `sda1`** to fix the root of your issue.

Comment: Indeed, there was a mismatch between the boot variables and the partition table. I removed the incorrect variables with "efibootmgr -b VAR -b" and added the correct variable with "efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sda -p EFIPARTNUMBER -l \EFI\GRUB\grubx64.efi -L Archlinux". After restart, boot fails and GRUB returns "unknown file system."

Comment: After rebooting, the boot variable value reverts back to the original incorrect value, different from the one set with the "efibootmgr -c" command. Subsequent attempts to rewrite the boot variable all yield the same result. I am inclined to believe that this anomaly is due to some issue with the MSDOS partition table. Therefore, to recover the system, I am forced to use an EFI partition on another hard disk.

Comment: Anyway, thank you very much for the guidance provided; in particular, I had never had the chance to learn how to use efibootmgr, a program that will surely be useful to me in the future.

Answer (score 0):

To recover the system I am forced to use an EFI partition on another hard disk. I believe that the anomaly is due to some issue with the MSDOS partition table.

Comment: You might be right: because Windows always requires GPT partitioning when booting in UEFI mode, firmware developers apparently don't spend much time testing the MBR partitioning + UEFI boot combination, so there may be quirky firmware behavior with that combo. Unfortunately there's very little a user can do, other than either find a way to live with the quirk, or send in a bug report to the hardware vendor and hope for a firmware update that will fix it.